# Calling an activity from an application from another application android

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to call an application's activity from within an activity of another application. What I'm doing here is:

```
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClassName("another_app_package_name", "another_app_package_name.class_name_in_that_package");

                startActivity(intent);
```

But my application is quitting throwing NoActivityFound exception saying that unable to find explicit activity class another_app_package_name.class_name_in_that_package.

I'm missing something obvious. I'm fairly new to Android platform.

Answer (score 8):

```
final Intent intent = new Intent();

ComponentName cName = new ComponentName
("package_name","package_name.class_name");

intent.setComponent(cName);         
startActivity(intent);
```

This will work. It worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will work:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("<package_name>", "<activity_class_name"));
context.startActivity(intent);
```

But the application that owns the activity you want to start must declare the activity with ["exported"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#exported) in its manifest.  The default for that option is false if the activity doesn't declare any intent filters.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
final Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN); //might not be necessary
i.setClassName("com.htc.android.worldclock", "com.htc.android.worldclock.WorldClockTabControl");
startActivity(i);
```

The class name - e.g. "com.htc.android.worldclock.WorldClockTabControl" - must be fully qualified.

If this isn't working, try calling the following method with your intent's class name string:

```
public static boolean isIntentAvailable(final Context context,
        final String action) {
    final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
    final List<ResolveInfo> list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(
            intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    return list.size() > 0;
}
```

and see what it returns.